# Swing: The graphics disappeared after the window is minimized

Tags: java, swing

I have a `Swing` class that generates some graphics and 2 buttons. The code is provided.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML {


    /* GoKart Colors
    String color1 = "#000000";
    String color2 = "#66CCCC";
    String color3 = "#B7D108";
    String color4 = "#E61E3F";
    String color5 = "#FBEC52";
    String color6 = "#9973AD";
    String color7 = "#F9A226";
    String color8 = "#6299EB";
    String colorBG= "#ffffff";
    */


    /* GoKart Colors
    String color1 = "#000000";
    String color2 = "#ff6672";
    String color3 = "#B7D999";
    String color4 = "#E61999";
    String color5 = "#FBEC52";
    String color6 = "#997999";
    String color7 = "#F9A226";
    String color8 = "#6299EB";
    String colorBG= "#ffffff";
    */


    /* Blue Corn
    String color1 = "#344152";
    String color2 = "#344152";
    String color3 = "#344152";
    String color4 = "#344152";
    String color5 = "#344152";
    String color6 = "#344152";
    String color7 = "#344152";
    String color8 = "#344152";
    String colorBG= "#ffffff";
    */

    /* White
    String color1 = "#ffffff";
    String color2 = "#ffffff";
    String color3 = "#ffffff";
    String color4 = "#ffffff";
    String color5 = "#ffffff";
    String color6 = "#ffffff";
    String color7 = "#ffffff";
    String color8 = "#ffffff";
    String colorBG= "#000000";
    */


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int sizeBig = 150;
    final static int canvasW = 1300;
    final static int canvasH = 750;

    int initialS = 1;
    int numberS = 40;
    int smallsizeVAR = sizeBig / 3;
    int border1 = 0;

    Random rand;


    /* Black  */
    String color1 = "#000000";
    String color2 = "#000000";
    String color3 = "#000000";
    String color4 = "#000000";
    String color5 = "#000000";
    String color6 = "#000000";
    String color7 = "#000000";
    String color8 = "#000000";
    String colorBG = "#ffffff";


    public GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML() {

        rand = new Random();
    }

    public void paint(final Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.decode(colorBG));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);

        while (initialS <= numberS) {

            final int randX = rand.nextInt(canvasW + sizeBig) + (0 - sizeBig);
            final int randY = rand.nextInt(canvasH + sizeBig) + (0 - sizeBig);

            final int sizeRANDx = rand.nextInt(((sizeBig + 1) - smallsizeVAR) + 1) + smallsizeVAR;
            final int sizeRANDy = sizeRANDx;


            final String[] arr = {color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7, color8};
            final Random random = new Random();
            final int select = random.nextInt(arr.length);

            g.setColor(Color.decode(arr[select]));
            g.fillRect(randX, randY, sizeRANDx, sizeRANDy);


            if (sizeRANDx > sizeRANDy) {
                border1 = (sizeRANDx - ((4 * sizeRANDx) / 5)) / 2;
            } else {
                border1 = (sizeRANDy - ((4 * sizeRANDy) / 5)) / 2;
            }

            g.setColor(Color.decode(colorBG));
            g.fillRect(randX + border1, randY + border1, sizeRANDx - (2 * border1), sizeRANDy - (2 * border1));

            initialS++;

            if (initialS == numberS + 1) {

                g.setColor(Color.decode(arr[select]));
                g.fillRect(canvasW / 8, canvasW / 8, (3 * sizeBig) / 2, (3 * sizeBig) / 2);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                final GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML demo = new GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML();

                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

                jFrame.setTitle("Latest Programic Art");
                jFrame.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);

                JButton save = new JButton("Save");
                JButton run = new JButton("Run Again");

                save.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
                run.setBounds(50, 500, 100, 50);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                panel.add(save);
                panel.add(run);

                JComponent canvas = new JComponent() {

                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        demo.paint(g);
                    }
                };

                jFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

                jFrame.setVisible(true);
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**The graphics generate fine, but, when I minimize the window it's all gone.** 
Secondly, I'm not able to see the buttons but if I provide the order of appending reversely,

```
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

I can see the buttons but not the drawings.

How do I correct the code?

Comment: This can be for the mixing AWT and Swing components. Im not very knowledgable in the Swing related works though.

Comment: The problems are 1) no super paintComponent call in your override, and most importantly 2) using setBounds and ignoring the existing BorderLayout that the contentPane is using.

Comment: If you need to create Swing GUI's, then read on the layout managers and use them to your advantage. Avoid `setBounds` and absolute layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while (initialS <= numberS) {
```

The paintComponent() method is called whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted. For example, when you restore the frame, the paintComponent() method is called.

In your case you don't reset the "initialS" variable to 0, so the loop never get executed the second time. So you need to reset the variable before you enter the loop.

```
save.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
run.setBounds(50, 500, 100, 50);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(save);
panel.add(run);
```

The setBounds(...) does nothing. You add the components to a JPanel. By default the JPanel uses a FlowLayout. The layout manager will reset the bounds based on the rules of the layout manager.

Don't attempt to set the bounds. Let the layout manager do its job.

> Secondly, I'm not able to see the buttons but if I provide the order of appending reversely,

The default layout manager for a JFrame is the BorderLayout. When you don't specify a constraint the component is added to the CENTER. The problem is you can only add one component to the CENTER, so only the last one added is visible.

Instead try:

```
jFrame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jFrame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

to see both components.

Also, typically you would:

1. add the custom painting code directly to the paintComponent() method of the component to keep all the logic in one place
2. override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the component so layout managers can work properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank you so much and the answer is very helpful. Both of the problems are solved. 

Do you know how can I run the program again after I click the `"Run Again"` button? The purpose is that if I don't like the graphics, I can re-run and get new graphics.

Comment: Another problem. The painting method shoutd NOT generate random numbers. That is it should NOT change the state of the graphics. Because every time you minimize/restore the frame you will see different graphics. Instead you need to add a method to your painting class like `generateGraphics()`. This will regenerate the random value and store them as instance variables of the class. Then the painting method just references these variables. Then your "Run Again" buttons just invokes the method and repaints the canvas. This is another reason all the painting logic should be in a single class.

Comment: I think the issue with that the `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` is called again after I minimize and again open the window?